# How iterating over two files and print their differences and show the position

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm coding this program where I have two different DNA sequences stored in two different files. I'm comparing the DNA sequences to see which characters are different and on which position they are different.
here is the code that I have so far, but I'm not getting the output that I want.

```
   WildDNAf = raw_input("Enter Wild DNA file: " )
   wildDNA = open(WildDNAf).read()
   MutDNAf = raw_input("Enter Mut DNA file: ")
   mutDNA = open (MutDNAf).read()


   dnacount = 0
   for i in range(len(wildDNA)):
       if wildDNA[i] != mutDNA:
           print i + 1 , wildDNA[i], mutDNA[i]
          dnacount = dnacount +1
   print "There are", dnacount, "Mutations"
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
There are 2589 Mutations
2590 T T
There are 2590 Mutations
2591 T T
There are 2591 Mutations
2592 G T
There are 2592 Mutations
2593 A G
There are 2593 Mutations
2594 A A
There are 2594 Mutations
```

I'm trying to have an output that shows a list of any mutations found between two sequences and on which positions that mutations were found.
The files for the DNA sequences can be found here https://uploadfiles.io/wpuey https://ufile.io/dzzvi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is this line, which compares a single character of `wildDNA` to the entire string in `mutDNA`.

```
if wildDNA[i] != mutDNA:
```

You probably want this instead, which will compare a single character of each (at the same index).

```
if wildDNA[i] != mutDNA[i]:
```

Also make sure that your indentation is correct. What you shared isn't valid Python due to the indentation, and your output makes me think that the `print` statement is inside the loop, even though the code you shared has it outside the loop.

**UPDATE**

Full working code with output (Python 3.x):

```
def read_dna_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        return ''.join(line.strip() for line in f.readlines()[1:])

a = read_dna_file('wild.fasta')
b = read_dna_file('mut.fasta')

assert len(a) == len(b)

count = 0

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != b[i]:
        print(i, a[i], b[i])
        count += 1

print("There are {} mutations.".format(count))

# Output:
# 0 T A
# 87 A G
# 88 A G
# 1307 G C
# 2367 T C
# There are 5 mutations.
```

Note that your files each contain a line at the top with different content (and different lengths). So you need to skip that before trying to do a character-by-character comparison, or almost everything in the file will fail to match. My `read_dna_file` function skips that first line and then also ignores the line breaks in the files.

Comment: I'm still getting a similar output
There are 1887 Mutations
There are 1887 Mutations
G T 2747

Comment: Please edit your question to include your current code and output.